# How to insert a sidebar in fl_chart?

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I'm trying to insert a sidebar next to the graph, as if it were a heat zone, to demonstrate user performance. However, the fl_chart package did not provide any support for this. In such a way that I can't do it any other way than in a Stack Widget. But this bar does not follow the values ​​of the Y axis, as shown in the attached image.

Code: I tried using a Stack to position the containers on the chart. But it was static

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      left: Platform.isAndroid ? 40 : 30,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
            width: 10,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .10,
            width: 10,
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          Container(
            height: Platform.isAndroid
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .115
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .080,
            width: 10,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    LineChart(...),
  ],
);
```